# nuxt store in external js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I decided to rewrite my application from spa vue to nuxt but i faced a problem in spa, in vue i could just import store and used it but in nuxt i cant do the same,  i am getting undefined object every time

in vue spa i had folder with some api services and with main api.js which include this code

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store/index'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: `http://myip.com/`,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${store.state.token}`
        }
    })
}
```

then in other js files i just import this api.js file and use something like this

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
    register (credetinals){
        return Api().post('register', credetinals)
    },
    login (credetinals){
        return Api().post('login', credetinals)
    }
}
```

so i had 10 js files services where i include api.js and then in files *.vue i just import this service
how can i do the same in nuxt ?

Comment: Can you console log `Api`?

Answer (score 0):

If you add your state under the `/store/index.js` it will automatically append in the application, you dont need to import it in your file.

What you can do is try to check the state using:

`window.$nuxt.$store.state`

Also dont forget to add a condition `process.browser` since you want to check it in browser.

Here is what I did in my api.js file for your reference:

```
// Libraries
import axios from 'axios';

// API Instance
export const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://myip.com/',
    headers: {},
    validateStatus: status => {
        return status;
    },
});

// API Interceptors
instance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    if (process.browser) {
        const userToken = window.$nuxt.$store.getters.getUserToken;
        // Set Authorization token
        if (userToken) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${userToken}`;
        }
    }
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: Hi, please do not post code images but actual text (with highlight).